# im doing a hangman and i need help to stop it guessing bewteen tw if statements

Tags: python

I wanna count how many letters are in the word that i'm trying to guess and each time i guess a word correctly the variable `correct_letters` will increase by `1`, but i don't even know why or how it sometimes increase by a lot of number and other times it doesn't even detect the condition that i put
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Ati.png)

beforehand thank you
here is the code

```
def hangman():
    myword = random_word () # this is just a random word that i chose from a list
    print(myword)
    used_letters= set()
    letters_guessed= ""
    #lookingfor = ""
    count = 4
    #loop til the user fail too many times
    correct_letters= 0

    while count > 0 or len(myword) > correct_letters:
        lookingfor= input(" guess the letter")
        letters_guessed = letters_guessed + lookingfor # put a letter to guess in the word
        used_letters =set(list(lookingfor))
        print(len(myword)) #for know the number of letters that has the word in order to do an if statement with both at the end
        print (correct_letters) #it is to measure how many letters we've guessed correctly
       
       
       
        print(f"you used the letters: {used_letters}")
        for letter in myword: # it evaluates each character in the variable "myword"
            if letter in letters_guessed: # it says that if the current character is equal to the word guessed it prints all the letter in that word
                    print( f"{letter}", end="")
                    correct_letters += 1
           
            else: #and else if the current character doesnt have the letter guessed it prints a "-" for example : "w-r-d"
                    print(f"-", end="")
        if correct_letters == len(myword):
            print(f"congratulations you guessed the word, it is {''.join(myword)}")
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes made:-**

```
(1) In every iteration in while `correct_letters initialised to 0`
(2) If user input the letter which is not present in the word `count decreased by 1`
(3) format the answer in readable way..
(4) add the condition. if user can't predict the word. user displayed **Better luck next time your chance are over.. the correct word is:...**
```

**Code:-**

```
def hangman():
    myword = "random" # this is just a random word that i chose from a list
    print(myword)
    used_letters= set()
    letters_guessed= ""
    #lookingfor = ""
    count = 4
    #loop til the user fail too many times
    correct_letters= 0

    while count > 0:
        
        lookingfor = input("\nguess the letter: ")
        
        if lookingfor not in myword:
            count-=1
            
        letters_guessed = letters_guessed + lookingfor # put a letter to guess in the word
        used_letters =set(list(lookingfor))
        print(len(myword)) #for know the number of letters that has the word in order to do an if statement with both at the end
        print(correct_letters) #it is to measure how many letters we've guessed correctly
       
        print(f"you used the letters: {used_letters}")
        correct_letters=0
        for letter in myword: # it evaluates each character in the variable "myword"
            if letter in letters_guessed: # it says that if the current character is equal to the word guessed it prints all the letter in that word
                    print( f"{letter} ", end="")
                    correct_letters+=1
            else: #and else if the current character doesnt have the letter guessed it prints a "-" for example : "w-r-d"
                    print(f"- ", end="")
        if correct_letters == len(myword):
            print(f"congratulations you guessed the word, it is {''.join(myword)}")
            break
    if not count:
        print("\nBetter luck next time your chance are over.. the correct word is: "+myword)

hangman()
```

**Output:-**
**When user guess correct:-**

```
random
guess the letter: r
6
0
you used the letters: {'r'}
r - - - - - 
guess the letter: a
6
1
you used the letters: {'a'}
r a - - - - 
guess the letter: n
6
2
you used the letters: {'n'}
r a n - - - 
guess the letter: d
6
3
you used the letters: {'d'}
r a n d - - 
guess the letter: o
6
4
you used the letters: {'o'}
r a n d o - 
guess the letter: m
6
5
you used the letters: {'m'}
r a n d o m congratulations you guessed the word, it is random
```

**When user can't get it right**

```
random
guess the letter: q
6
0
you used the letters: {'q'}
- - - - - - 
guess the letter: z
6
0
you used the letters: {'z'}
- - - - - - 
guess the letter: p
6
0
you used the letters: {'p'}
- - - - - - 
guess the letter: t
6
0
you used the letters: {'t'}
- - - - - - 
Better luck next time your chance are over.. the correct word is: random
```